# DnD How to manage sub lists inside main list? using @react-beautiful-dnd

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-beautiful-dnd

I have a list like that:

```js
  const list = [
    {
      key: 'parent1',
      text: 'parent 1',
      subList: [
        {key: 'child1', text: 'Child 1'},
        {key: 'child2', text: 'Child 2'}
      ]
    },
    {
      key: 'parent2',
      text: 'Parent 2',
      subList: [
        {key: 'child1', text: 'Child 1'},
        {key: 'child2', text: 'Child 2'}
      ]
    }
  ]
```

I need to create draggable items for this list that the parents will be one main list that can be replaced, and for any sub list I need to create draggable sub list that the items can be replaced inside. I a bit confused how to do that since I need to create `<DragDropContext...>` for the parent list and one for any sub list, but how can we deal with the `onDragEnd` since this may be should update dynamically by the specific list we work on. Does any one manage with such a situation?
It seems something like this:

[image]